# Filtering Data using a macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a line of code to filter out data using a macro in excel. I am wanting it to filter out two different criteria on one column. Please see the code below. From looking on google, it should work but it isnt..

```
Sub Unmet_Projects()

With Sheet1
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:CA1").AutoFilter
    .Range("A1:CA1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Fulfilled", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="Requested", VisibleDropDown:=False                    
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be `Operator:=xlOr` and not `Operator:=xlAnd` since the values in column 3 (column `C`) can be only `Fulfilled` **or** `Requested`.

If you wish to include more values in the filter then I'd recommend the following instead:

```
.Range("A1:CA1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("Fulfilled", "Requested", "Partially Assigned", "Not yet assigned", "Assigned", "etc..."), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Perfect, that works thank you. Is it possible to add more criteria. I actually have another 4 values that are required to be filtered. I have tried this but it overwrites the first value.

Comment: Sub Unmet_Projects1()

    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        . Range("A1:CA1").AutoFilter
        .Range("A1:CA1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Fulfilled",     Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Requested", VisibleDropDown:=True
        .Range("A1:CA1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Partially Assigned", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Soft Booked",     VisibleDropDown:=True
    End With

    End Sub

Comment: If this solution solves your problem then please mark this post as solved. If you have a new question then please post a new question.