# VBA .AutoFilter Method from Time Now

Tags: vba, excel

I need to filter Field 10 dates to show all data for the previous 8 months, including the current month, and dates with 01/01/1900 dates and then delete those rows.
I then need to apply the same filter in Field 9, but for a 17 months month range (7 behind, 9 ahead). Any suggestions?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$M$20368").AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "1/29/2016", 1, "2/29/2016", 1, "3/31/2016", 0, _
    "12/23/2015", 0, "12/22/2014", 0, "12/19/2013", 0, "12/20/2012", 0, "12/22/2011", 0, _
    "12/20/2010", 0, "12/23/2009", 0, "12/22/2008", 0, "12/20/2007", 0, "12/21/2006", 0, _
    "12/21/2005", 0, "12/21/2004", 0, "12/17/2003", 0, "12/19/2002", 0, "12/20/2001")
Rows("5:20366").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$M$17496").AutoFilter Field:=9
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$M$17496").AutoFilter Field:=10
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$M$17496").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "7/30/2105", 0, "1/2/2045" _
    , 0, "5/7/2019", 0, "4/27/2018", 1, "8/31/2017", 1, "9/26/2017", 1, "10/27/2017", 1, _
    "11/30/2017", 1, "12/21/2017", 1, "1/31/2016", 1, "2/29/2016", 1, "3/31/2016", 0, _
    "12/23/2015", 0, "12/23/2014", 0, "12/20/2013", 0, "12/27/2012", 0, "12/23/2011", 0, _
    "12/22/2010", 0, "12/23/2009", 0, "12/24/2008", 0, "12/21/2007", 0, "12/27/2006", 0, _
    "12/23/2005", 0, "12/26/2004", 0, "12/24/2003", 0, "12/25/2002", 0, "12/21/2001", 0, _
    "6/30/2000", 0, "10/4/1999", 0, "11/1/1996")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering Data using a macro in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400396/filtering-data-using-a-macro-in-excel)

Comment: `.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate & " 23:59:59"` I'd take a look at using a filter between selection as I believe this is what you are after.